# Heap Analytics - How do I capture the amount of time users spend on a page?

Tags: analytics

I am using Heap Analytics to track events (page clicks and page views), but once registering the event I am having difficulty in finding how to measure how long user views a page.

The only place similar to this measurement is in the graphs, under average time between, for pages where I select page view, along with a start and end event.

If this is the method to track event for page view, what is the start, and what is the end event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE 25NOV16: After using a similar method for a little while to track user exits (and thus, total session time), I can say that the below method works, but not 100% of the time. It's unclear to me what determines the success (latency, maybe).

after my comment (which i deleted) i did a little testing and i have a solution, but it requires a custom event, so you can't do any retroactive analysis.

First, define a `page_view` event for whichever page.

Then, in your page, add this snippet:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  heap.track('pageExited', {arbitraryProp: "string"})
}
```

Then, in the graph view of the heap dashboard, you can select `average time between`, `page_view`, and `pageExited`.

Note that `onbeforeunload` will fire when user refreshes, in addition to when user exits page.

Comment: What would you say the success rate was for you? For me out of 1000 page view events i'm only seeing 220 page exit events. Does that sound similar to your success rate?

Comment: 1. It might be a good number, to confirm, think about it this way, if users didn't exit from this page, they should visit another page, correct? 
2. So in this case, they will visit another page and the main page will be considered the previous page.  Just count how many time it is a previous pages (it should be around 780 out of 1000 in this case)